How to troubleshoot pymol downloaded from repository?
In my Ubuntu device 24.04 LTS I am downloading pymol from repository by using sudo apt-get install -y pymol. I am successfully installing pymol but whenever I am trying to open it, its shows nothing regardless whether I am using the application or accessing from the terminal.

An apt install will download from whatever sources/repositories you have added to your system, so that could be official or third party if you've added third party sources. You can explore what is install using apt policy pymol (and see what options are). I'm not familiar with the app sorry, but if it crashes I'd look for clues in a crash report (/var/crash/), system logs (journalctl, dmesg etc) but further would require knowledge of the app (which I don't possess)
